# Python calling a function every 60 seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I work with Python and kivy. I have a function that returns a `list` and that list is updated every minute.

I want that function to be called again every 60 seconds.

`kivy` have a `Clock` method **BUT** the function must be **callable** and my function is not because it returns a `list`.

The return of my function:

[image]

The code I want it to be recalled every 60 seconds :

```html
# Get & ADD TRAFIC_LIST TO TRAFIC SECTION
self.trafic_list = Arret.get_cross_lignes_with_times(self.station["id_arret"])
self.trafic = self.root.ids.trafic_bar
for trafic in self.trafic_list:
            
   card = TraficCard(destination=trafic[1], remaining=trafic[2], next_bus="bus", number=trafic[3])
            self.trafic.add_widget(card)
```

Comment: so where is the function?

Comment: Arret.get_cross_lignes_with_times(self.station["id_arret"])

or do you want the whole function !!

Comment: I believe that [`sched`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) should point you in the right direction in setting up a simple event scheduler.

Comment: Put that entire block of code that you posted into a method, and use `Clock.schedule_interval()` to schedule that new method every 60 seconds.